# shell scripts runs manually but not in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

i have shell script to FTP a file from one server to another server called abc.sh below is the code inside it

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='10.18.11.168'
USER='india'
PASS='India@2017'
FILE='inload.dat'
DIRECTORY='/inloading'


ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER $PASS
cd $DIRECTORY
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

i am able to run it using ./abc.sh and file also gets copied to remote server.

But when i use in crontab it is not ftp the file
below is the crontab entry

```
15 01 * * * /user/loader/abc.sh > /user/loader/error.log 2>&1
```

in the error.log it shows as `local: inload.dat: No such file or directory`

Comment: did you check manually that file exists or not?

Comment: yes the file exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local path is probably not what you want it to be. Before executing the ftp command, add a cd to the directory of where the file is located. Or have the full path name to the file $FILE.

Comment: This is just a suggestion that would better fit as a comment. A good answer would include specific instructions that the original poster and other people who stumble upon this post could use directly.

Comment: "add a cd to the directory of where the file is located" is a very specific instruction.

Comment: added a cd to the directory before FTP now working, thank you all for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the file `inload.dat`, which is relative to the directory *the script is run from*. When you run the script as `./abc.sh` it looks for an `inload.dat` in the same directory.

Cron chooses which directory to run your script from when it executes (IIRC it generally defaults to `/root` or your `HOME` directory, but the specific location doesn't matter), and it's not necesarily the same directory that you're in when you run `./abc.sh`.

The right solution is to make `FILE` and absolute path to the full location of `inload.dat`, so that your script no longer depends on being run from a certain directory in order to succeed.

There are other options, such as dynamically [determining the directory the script lives in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/113632), but simply using absolute paths is generally the better choice.

Comment: Another solution that may be convenient if multiple files are to be uploaded is to use the `lcd` ftp command.

Comment: Hi dimo414 i tried giving FILE='/user/loader/inload.dat' in abc.sh and still not copying now getting error in error.log as '/user/loader/inload.dat': cannot write.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. You've fixed your original bug, now onto the next one! "cannot write" generally suggests a permissions issue, but without more context I can't say for sure. I'd suggest trying to debug a little further and then posting a new question.

Comment: added a cd to the directory before FTP now working, thanks for your help.